# check if a char is a single quote. c++

Tags: c++, char, equals

I want to check if a char is a single quote.
Here is my code.

```
char mychar;
if (mychar == '\'')  // Is that how we check this char is a single quote?
{
  cout << "here is a quote" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Then what is the problem with your code?

Comment: What's wrong with trying it?

Comment: Thank you for reply. I want to is that how we USUALLY check if a char is a single quote?

Comment: You can also check this by running this program...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about working code; try posting on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code snippet is invalid. Instead of

```
char mychar;
if(char=='\'')// is that how we check this char is a single quote?
{
  cout<<"here is a quote"<<endl;
}
```

there must be

```
char mychar;
if(mychar=='\'')// is that how we check this char is a single quote?
{
  cout<<"here is a quote"<<endl;
}
```

And moreover object `mychar` must be initialized.

As for other then indeed you have to use character literal that contains escape symbol of single quote.

Or if you have a string literal like

const char *quote = "'";

then you can write either as

```
if( mychar == *quote )
```

or

```
if( mychar == quote[0] )
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes. (Assuming you fix the typo where you have `char` instead of `mychar`.)